# How to plot intensity distribution of Laguerree Gaussian Function LG(pl)?

Tags: plotting

As LG(0,1)=-(1√2)[HG(0,2)+HG(2,0)] Laguerree Gaussian of p=0 & l=1 gives us Hermite Gaussian with modes (0,2) & (2,0) i want to draw the intensity distribution of the LG(0,1) how to calculate the intensity?

Comment: Please provide more information. This is unanswerable at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Wolfram Demonstrations project here under CC BY-NC-SA license by Enrique Zeleny May 2014 - download the source: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LaguerreGaussianModesOfParaxialWaveEquation

I know little about optics so I couldn't comment on it, but here is the essential part of the code:

```
f[l_, p_, r_, ϕ_] := (r Sqrt[2])^
  Abs[l] Exp[-r^2] LaguerreL[p, Abs[l], 2 r^2] Exp[I r^2/2] Exp[
   I l ϕ] Exp[I (2 p + Abs[l] + 1)]

Manipulate[
 If[view == "2D", 
  DensityPlot[
   Evaluate[Abs@f[l, p, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]]], {x, -2, 
    2 }, {y, -2, 2 }, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {400, 400}],
  Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs@f[l, p, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]]], {x, -2,
     2 }, {y, -2, 2 }, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {400, 400}]], {{l, 3, 
   Style["l", Italic]}, 0, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{p, 5, Style["p", Italic]}, 0, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {view, {"2D", "3D"}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```